# weird wampserver ip/port conflict

Tags: apache, webserver, wampserver, portforwarding

Ok, here is my problem:
I am runing WampServer 2.5 on my windows 7 Home Premium PC and I have a TP-Link TL-WR642G v2 router updated to the latest official firmware ([download site](http://www.tp-link.com/en/support/download/?model=TL-WR642G&version=V2)). I have forwarded port 80 to my pc (ip 192.168.1.111, static) and disabled all the firewalls (see images). When i turn on WAMP, and enter localhost or 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.1.111 or even my wan ip (93.103.90.XXX) everything connects and I get my test html page but when I enter my wan ip on any machine that is not connected to my router the page doesn't load - i don't even get 403 forbidden (and yes my wamp says server online an i have edited the httpd.conf). Also http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ and http://www.whatsmyip.org/port-scanner/ say port 80 is closed/timed out. Everything worked fine a week ago and i could access my server from anywhere with my public ip. I also tried other ports but i get the same thing, tried WAMP 2.4 with no success. All i did from last week was downgrade from Ultimate to Home Premium and install the drivers of course (but I guess that has no effect) and upgraded my router firmware (linked above). Any idea why it doesn't work? Does anyone have the older firmware, so I can try downgrading to it?

Thank you for reading, David :O
[image: windows firewall][image: port forwarding][image: router firewall]

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done so already; then change the Management port of the Router to something other than port 80. That way you aren't conflicting with the WampServer. This is more than likely the issue.

You shouldn't have to change anything in the Firewall as Virtual Servers will set a rule to allow the packets.

As a test can you try to open up other ports on your computer like **SSH** or **Telnet**. If you find the that forwarding settings work to these protocols then you know the issue is not with the Router or ISP, but with a firewall setting on the Computer.

You can use this site to see if your ports are open (if you are on the LAN): http://www.canyouseeme.org/

Comment: i opened a teamspeak server and i am able to connect with it with my public ip. I changed the router management port to 1234, but there's still a problem. Might have to give up on this one :( EDIT: Also tried it on linux with no success.